# Relational Algebra Union

Tags: database, relational-database, tuples, union, algebra

Given two relations R1 and R2, where R1 contains N1 tuples, R2 contains N2
tuples, and N2 > N1 > 0, give the minimum and maximum possible sizes (in
tuples) for the resulting relation produced by each of the following relational
algebra expressions. In each case, state any assumption about the schemas for
R1 and R2 needed to make the expression meaningful:

3.1) R1 ∪ R2

How would I go about working this out? I'm assuming the minimum size is 3 tuples and maximum is R1+R2? But I could be wrong..

Comment: This sounds a lot like homework so tread carefully and don't expect full answers. That said, consider that the answer depends on whether or not your relational algebra permits duplicate elements -- and consider that a union of two empty sets is an empty set (though in this specific case you've ruled out empty sets). Actual relational algebra *does not*, but SQL *does* (SQL is a weird mutant that is neither an algebra nor a calculus... bleh), so sometimes you will get some weird interpretations of this when discussing "relational algebra" in the context of real-world databases.

Comment: To those interested : Minimum  - the overall number of tuples is if all tuples from N1 were also in R2, Maximum - if there were no tuples from R1 in R2 (vice versa).